# In Linux, how to measure/sampling GPIO pulse width

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio, pwm

My board was running ARM Linux. It will be having a GPIO to connect to an input signal, which encodes information with different pulse width but the same period.  Say the period is 10ms, and a 2ms (high) pulse will present 0 and 5ms pulse will present 1.

In Linux, user space or kernel space, how do I sample this kind of continuous pulse-width shift signal? If it was a bare MCU, I know I can use a hardware clock with pulse-width-measure mode. But I did not find relevant information on Linux.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: There is no way to get it reliably. First steps to mitigate is to pin process to a separate CPU and unload it from other tasks (basically wasting full core to do something which should be done by MCU). Second step, is switching to RT Linux. And proper solution is to use MCU with RTOS (e.g. Zephyr).

Comment: But of course you may try. What you need is a *dedicated* timer and GPIO pin set as interrupt by both edges. Whenever interrupted the driver has to start or stop timer and convert encoded data to whatever you want.

Comment: If your hardware supports that mode, I.e. PWM decoding, you simply need a driver.

Comment: @0andriy I suppose what you mean by PWM decoding is that same thing as I said PW-Measurement.  I see Linux had PW-Modulation, but not PW-Measurement.  This looks hard to believe.  My MCU has hardware clocks that support working in the pulse measurement mode.  So do you mean I have to write my own PW-Measurement driver?

Comment: Why is it hard to believe? I seems no one needed it so far. There is even no framework for that. (It looks like IIO subsystem is a closest one, but I don't see any sensor support there for PWM decoding / reading).

Answer (score 0):

The reason no one can give you a concrete answer is because what you're asking for is specific to the CPU in question.  It can be done if the hardware supports it...  For example, the Texas Instruments Jacinto6 processor, one I use, has M4 cores that can run code like a micro-controller and one of the M4 cores could be configured to handle an IRQ on a mapped GPIO.  Then then when different pulse widths are detected, you could send the information to Linux running the A15 cores of the same chip.  The NXP iMX family of processors, has hardware support for this too but it's not on a dedicated core like the Ti chip.  For the iMX6, you could set up a GPIO to generate the IRQ with the the delta-time (from clock tree) pushed into a memory mapped register.  In this case, a different Linux driver would be needed to read the memory mapped register than the Ti based solution because of the hardware differences.  Hope this helps shed light on why you won't simply find the capability already there in a Linux kernel/driver....